# Scraping Search Results Using Soup and Python, Split Returns Only One Value Instead Of a List?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, split

When trying to scrape google search results using Soup and Python 3.0x+, the result after a split is only one value which is one URL from a number of urls.

Expected Output is list of all the urls found instead of one, which then will be cleaned using head,sep,tail partition method.

It happens after this for loop.

```
 for link in links:
  x = re.split('="/url?q="',link["href"].replace("/url?q=",""))
```

the value links has all the results from the search page and the loop is supposed to iterate through all the links using the parameter link:

Full Code

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse 
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request



srchTerm = ['64503']



class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
      version = "Mozilla/5.0"

opener = AppURLopener()
parser = 'html.parser'  # or 'lxml' (preferred) or 'html5lib', if installed

for term in srchTerm:
 resp = opener.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://private.xx.co.bd/++" + term)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, parser, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))
links = soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(https://private.xx.co.bd/)"))

for link in links:
       x = re.split('="/url?q="',link["href"].replace("/url?q=",""))



## for linka in x: 
           ##head, sep, tail = linka.('&sa')
           ##print(head)
```

This Prints only one result of:

```
<a data-uch="1" href="/url?q=https://private.xx.co.bd/blalbalba/4B1041344.aspx&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi-pOWSv4HqAhWGJTQIHUI-BCgQFjACegQIAxAB&amp;usg=AOvVaw3joBh4SH9QwW5WHmwn-7cs"><h3 class="zBAuLc"><div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd"><span dir="rtl">xxxxxxx</span></div></h3><div class="BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd"><span dir="rtl">xxx‹ https://private.xxx.co.il</span></div></a>
```

Comment: Can you try adding a datastructure before your split x = list(re.split(.....)).

Comment: What is the expected output, please include that in the post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried, still one result.

Comment: What value of `link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")` you are getting

Comment: @EduardoSavrin value is : `['https://private.xxx.co.bd/blabla/401C04134777625D49130612.aspx&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiZqq6CzoHqAhVCFzQIHRqDDqEQFjADegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1yskV6XYDuxzezGskZGGiW']`

Comment: @NoneNoneNone I think you should append value in line `x = re.split('="/url?q="',link["href"].replace("/url?q=",""))`
Try Changing it to `x.append(re.split('="/url?q="',link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")))` Assuming `x` is list

Comment: @EduardoSavrin Thanks, but "x" is just a value I added as a parameter of the output, its not a list. I've tried it on the list of urls which is the value "links" but still not working.reuslt of using links: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @NoneNoneNone I mean to say store results of `re.split('="/url?q="',link["href"].replace("/url?q=",""))` somewhere instead of assigning it ot `x` so that you can all values once the loop ends.